# Using CSR's 2-mic bluetooth headset program without actually placing a telephone call

Tags: microcontrollers, bluetooth, csr-adk

I am asking about the CSR 8675 Bluetooth audio chip (the solution to this problem will be similar in the other related chips in the same family) and I am using ADK4.0.1

The CSR 8675 contains [VM (virtual machine)](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/834/what-is-the-difference-between-mcu-vm-firmware-and-kalimba-dsp-in-the-csr8675) on top of a XAP based processor, and it contains a kalimba DSP that handles most of the actual audio processing. It also has bluetooth stack called Bluestack that handles bluetooth communications

ADK4.0.1 comes with a sample project called Sink project (runs on VM), which has another sample sub-project called cvc-2mic-headset (runs on kalimba). This Sink project makes the CSR chip work as a bluetooth headset

After the CSR chip with the sink project downloaded into it is paired with a smartphone, if I call the smartphone, the cvc-2mic-headset kalimba project gets loaded which handles SBC encoding/decoding (encoding the incoming CSR microphone data to send it out to the smartphone via bluetooth/decoding audio data that the smartphone is sending the CSR chip via bluetooth) as well as performs some noise reduction operation using the CVC proprietary library

Normally, the CSR module is paired with a smartphone, an incoming/outgoing call happens, the cvc-2mic-headset kalimba project gets loaded and the CSR module starts acting as a bluetooth headset

I have made some custom modifications to the cvc-2mic-headset project and want to test my program without having to make a telephone call every time. Is it possible to somehow simulate a telephone call from within the CSR chip, and make it think that an SCO link has been established (as far as I understand, the feature that transfers audio data between the CSR chip and the smartphone via bluetooth during telephone call is known as an SCO link, and the cvc-2mic-headset kalimba project gets loaded only after the VM detects the presence of an SCO connection, but correct me here if I am wrong)?

Comment: Do you want to avoid making calls because of costs or simply it is too problematic to make a call every time?

Comment: both, and also I want to test my custom modifications on the cvc-2mic-headset project without the presence of a phone call